Symfony 7: default-entry_options for inheritor of CollectionType with
I have a bit of a tricky situation: I defined a basic inheritor of CollectionType like this with the goal to make including collections in my app simpler and make some standard behaviours of the front-end easier to configure for example:
abstract class AbstractSimpleCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    abstract protected function getEntryTypeClassname(): string;

    protected function getDataClassName(): string
    {
        return "";
    }

    public function getParent(): string
    {
        return CollectionType::class;
    }

    protected function getEntryOptions($options): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        //???
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options): void
    {
        parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);

        $view->vars['prioritizable'] = $options['prioritizable'];
        // + more configurable settings
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'prioritizable' => false,
            'entry_type' => $this->getEntryTypeClassname(),
            'entry_options' => [],
            'error_bubbling' => false,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'keep_as_list' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'constraints' => [
                new Valid(),
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix(): string
    {
        return "simple_collection";
    }
}

I thought implementing buildForm doing something like this:
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $entryOptions = array_merge(
            $this->getEntryOptions($options),
            [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'f-listItemBox'],
            ],
            $options['entry_options']
        );

        if (!empty($this->getDataClassName())) {
            $entryOptions = array_merge($entryOptions, ['data_class' => $this->getDataClassName(),]);
        }

        $options['entry_options'] = $entryOptions;

        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    }

would propagate the entry-options to my entry-type but it seems like it doesn't. When I dump the options within the buildForm-method of my type-class for the entries the entry-options are gone.
Example:
class WeightedControlledTermDropDownArrayType extends AbstractSimpleCollectionType
{
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options): void
    {
        parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);

        $view->vars['skosmosGroup'] = $options['skosmos_group'];
        $view->vars['skosmosCollection'] = $options['skosmos_collection'];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'placeholder' => "",
            'skosmos_group' => "",
            'skosmos_collection' => "",
        ]);
    }

    protected function getEntryOptions($options): array
    {
        return [
            'label' => false,
            'placeholder' => $options['placeholder'],
            'skosmos_group' => $options['skosmos_group'],
            'skosmos_collection' => $options['skosmos_collection'],
        ];
    }

    protected function getEntryTypeClassname(): string
    {
        return WeightedControlledTermDropDownType::class;
    }

    protected function getDataClassName(): string
    {
        return WeightedControlledTerm::class;
    }
}

and if I now try to simply control if the options have been passed to WeightedControlledTermDropDownType by dd(...)-ing the options:
class WeightedControlledTermDropDownType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        dd($options);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'placeholder' => "",
            'skosmos_group' => "",
            'skosmos_collection' => "",
            'labelClass' => "f-mainLabel",
            'data_class' => WeightedControlledTerm::class,
        ]);
    }
}

it will only write out the $options with basic default values.
I am using the WeightedControlledTermDropDownArrayType like this:
class WorkType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('methodClassifications', WeightedControlledTermDropDownArrayType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => false,
                'skosmos_group' => 'methods',
                'skosmos_collection' => 'allMethods',
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Work::class,
        ]);
    }
}

Part of my goals is to avoid having to define the entry_type-options in every place where I use the type, so with my approach I tried to combine default config with possibly manually set additional key/values.
So what am I doing wrong?

Solved by dropping the attempt to do this within the form-type-inheritance-system and inheriting CollectionType directly while overriding buildForm with a very similar method to the original one but augmenting things with my own options.
Looks like this (if someone knows a way to do it more elegantly, please tell me!)
abstract class AbstractSimpleCollectionType extends CollectionType
{
    abstract protected function getEntryTypeClassname(): string;

    protected function getDataClassName(): string
    {
        return "";
    }

    protected function getEntryOptions($options): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $entryOptions = array_merge(
            $this->getEntryOptions($options),
            [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'f-listItemBox'],
            ],
            $options['entry_options']
        );

        if (!empty($this->getDataClassName())) {
            $entryOptions = array_merge($entryOptions, ['data_class' => $this->getDataClassName(),]);
        }

        $options['entry_options'] = $entryOptions;

        $resizePrototypeOptions = null;
        if ($options['allow_add'] && $options['prototype']) {
            $resizePrototypeOptions = array_replace($options['entry_options'], $options['prototype_options']);
            $prototypeOptions = array_replace([
                'required' => $options['required'],
                'label' => $options['prototype_name'] . 'label__',
            ], $resizePrototypeOptions);

            if (null !== $options['prototype_data']) {
                $prototypeOptions['data'] = $options['prototype_data'];
            }

            $prototype = $builder->create($options['prototype_name'], $options['entry_type'], $prototypeOptions);
            $builder->setAttribute('prototype', $prototype->getForm());
        }

        $resizeListener = new ResizeFormListener(
            $options['entry_type'],
            $options['entry_options'],
            $options['allow_add'],
            $options['allow_delete'],
            $options['delete_empty'],
            $resizePrototypeOptions,
            $options['keep_as_list']
        );

        $builder->addEventSubscriber($resizeListener);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options): void
    {
        parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);

        $view->vars['prioritizable'] = $options['prioritizable'];
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'prioritizable' => false,
            'entry_type' => $this->getEntryTypeClassname(),
            'entry_options' => [],
            'error_bubbling' => false,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'keep_as_list' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'constraints' => [
                new Valid(),
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix(): string
    {
        return "simple_collection";
    }
}

